# making a double/int out of Point.getX() and .getY()

Tags: java, distance, point

i'm trying to calculate the distance between 2 points with Java Point, it works fine till i say for example: double point1x = point1.getX();. cause when i do, i receive a error.
can somebody help me find the problem in my code?

```
public class ClickAndCalc extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

public ClickAndCalc() throws IOException{
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public static void Window() throws IOException {
    String path = "kaakfoto.jpg";                       //imported image
    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));    //add the image to the JLabel

    System.out.println("height: " + height);            //print out the height and width of the image
    System.out.println("width: " + width);

    ClickAndCalc frame = new ClickAndCalc();            //make a new frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    frame.setSize(width+3, height+26);                  //set the size of the frame the same as the size of the image
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

int i=0;
Point p1, p2, p3;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {    //when clicked add point for 3 times

    if(i==0) {
        p1 = e.getPoint();
        System.out.println("coordinates Point1: X=" + p1.getX() + ". Y=" + p1.getY());
    }
    else if(i==1) {
        p2 = e.getPoint();
        System.out.println("coordinates Point2: X=" + p2.getX() + ". Y=" + p2.getY());
    }
    else if(i==2) {
        p3 = e.getPoint();
        System.out.println("coordinates Point3: X=" + p3.getX() + ". Y=" + p3.getY());
    }
    i++;
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

//down here is some mistake i can't find

double distanceAB(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
}

double  x1 = p1.getX(),     //convert getX and getY to doubles
        y1 = p1.getY(),
        x2 = p2.getX(),
        y2 = p2.getY(),
        distanceAB;{

distanceAB = distanceAB(x1, y1, x2, y2);        //calculate the distance between point A and B
System.out.println("the distance between the points AB is " + distanceAB + ".");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Window();                                   //add the window (frame, label, image)
}
```

}

Comment: this is what i get in the console: height: 1840
width: 1360
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ClickAndCalc.<init>(ClickAndCalc.java:74)
 at ClickAndCalc.Window(ClickAndCalc.java:32)
 at ClickAndCalc.main(ClickAndCalc.java:85)

Comment: @laurensloo So which line in the mess of code you've posted corresponds with line 74 in your actual code?

Comment: when i make the double: -  double  x1 = p1.getX(),  //convert getX and getY to doubles
   y1 = p1.getY(),
   x2 = p2.getX(),
   y2 = p2.getY(),
   distanceAB;{

Comment: `double  x1 = p1.getX()` after `Point p1, p2, p3;` of course it throws NPE

Comment: Are you sure that's where the exception is getting thrown ? I would rather say there is a problem when reading the image in the method `Window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
double  x1 = p1.getX(),     //convert getX and getY to doubles
        y1 = p1.getY(),
        x2 = p2.getX(),
        y2 = p2.getY(),
        distanceAB;
```

You are defining member variable of the class `ClickAndCalc`. These member variables are initialized when a new instance of the class is created, and that is the moment `p1.getX()`, `p1.getY()`, `p2.getX()` and `p2.getY()` are called. At this point, however, `p1` and `p2` are `null`, so you get a `NullPointerException`.

You can call calculate the distance between `p1` and `p2` only when you've determined the coordinates, that is, after you've clicked twice on the frame. The easiest solution is to move the code to the `mousePressed` method:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {    //when clicked add point for 3 times

    if (i==0) {
    ...
    }
    else if (i==1) {
        p2 = e.getPoint();
        System.out.println("coordinates Point2: X=" + p2.getX() + ". Y=" + p2.getY());

        double x1 = p1.getX();
        double y1 = p1.getY();
        double x2 = p2.getX();
        double y2 = p2.getY();
        double distanceAB = distanceAB(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        System.out.println("the distance between the points AB is " + distanceAB + ".");
    }
    ... 
}
```